# Does NPM install <pkg> also runs npm start of that pkg?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Does `npm i -S <pkg/module>` or `yarn add <pkg/module>` also runs the `start` script written in the `package.json` of that specific pkg/module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it just installs the package recursively and add it to your `package.json`

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install for reference

The script `postinstall` is run after installation

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts for reference